# How to edit code fields in word document using apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to edit existing word document containing some placeholders, some of those are in code fields (those from Ctrl+F9) and I have no clue how to easily replace contents of these fields.

I've tried editing these placeholders to a new text directly in XMLObject of my document, but after saving the file I cannot open it - Word says that my file is corrupted and cannot be open.

This is what I've tried while playing with Apache POI.

```java
public void myFunc(List<MyObject> codeList) {
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(destFile.getPath());
            XWPFDocument xwpfDocument = new XWPFDocument(fis)){
            XmlObject xmlObject = xwpfDocument.getDocument();
            String xmlString = xmlObject.toString();
            int currentIndex = 1;
            for (MyObject current : codeList) {
                for (int j = 0; j < current.getCount(); j++, currentIndex++) {
                    String currentTitlePlaceholder = "ABCDEF00" + String.format("%02d", currentIndex);
                    String currentFieldCodePlaceholder = String.format("%013d", currentIndex);
                    xmlString = xmlString.replace(currentFieldCodePlaceholder, current.getCode());
                    xmlString = xmlString.replace(currentTitlePlaceholder, current.getTitle());
                }
            }
            XmlObject newXmlObject = XmlObject.Factory.parse(xmlString);
            xwpfDocument.getDocument().set(newXmlObject);
            xwpfDocument.getDocument().save(destFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you confusing Word fields (Ctrl+F9) and Content Controls. The only field I know of with placeholder text is the Macrobutton field used as a prompt. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Prompts

Comment: `xwpfDocument.getDocument().save(destFile);` saves the XML of document part `document.xml` into `destFile`. That is not a `*.docx` file then. I would do `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);xwpfDocument.write(out);out.close();` instead.

Comment: @AxelRichter is correct. Created a sample code with his suggestion [here](https://github.com/vasant-techie/docx-poi.git)

Comment: It worked, thank you very much @AxelRichter